# In C language, if the array members is not assigned a value when they are initialized, is the initial value random?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks

When I was reading the source code/kernel/sched.c of the Linux 0.96a version,
I found that the averunnable array was not assigned a value when it was initialized, so I wondered whether this would cause its array members'value becomes a random number when it is used.
source link: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/0.96a/source/kernel/sched.c
line 355: unsigned long averunnable[3];   /* fixed point numbers */

1. I tried to read the relevant source code, but I didn't find where this averunnable array is assigned a value.
2. I tried to run this code segment  and found that when this array member is used, the initial value is random.

```c
# cat testaverunnable.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{

#define FSHIFT  11
#define FSCALE  (1<<FSHIFT)
/*
 * Constants for averages over 1, 5, and 15 minutes
 * when sampling at 5 second intervals.
 */
static unsigned long cexp[3] = {
        1884,   /* 0.9200444146293232 * FSCALE,  exp(-1/12) */
        2014,   /* 0.9834714538216174 * FSCALE,  exp(-1/60) */
        2037,   /* 0.9944598480048967 * FSCALE,  exp(-1/180) */
};
unsigned long averunnable[3];   /* fixed point numbers */

        int i, n=10;
        printf("before into for cycle, the averunnable [%u] is %u \n",i, averunnable[i]);

        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                {
                        printf("averunnable [%u] is %u \n",i, averunnable[i]);
                        averunnable[i] = (cexp[i] * averunnable[i] + n * FSCALE * (FSCALE - cexp[i])) >> FSHIFT;
                        printf("atfer calculation, the averunnable [%u] is %u \n",i, averunnable[i]);
                }

    return 0;
}
```

```bash
# gcc -o testaverunnable testaverunnable.c
# ./testaverunnable
before into for cycle, the averunnable [0] is 4195856 
averunnable [0] is 4195856 
atfer calculation, the averunnable [0] is 3861499 
averunnable [1] is 4195392 
atfer calculation, the averunnable [1] is 4126081 
averunnable [2] is 3756023344 
atfer calculation, the averunnable [2] is 3805055516
```

This is the Linus kernel, so I think I must have overlooked something, please help me, thanks!

Comment: It's not "random".  Attempting to read the value is "undefined behavior".

Comment: Not random .. _something_ has to exist in memory, there's no "absence of value" state. If you don't initialize, then who knows what's there.

Comment: But in this case, the variable is defined outside of a function, so it is initialized to 0.

Comment: FYI: (reacting to OP title). Arrays have **elements**, not _members_. You're asking about when the array is **defined**, not _initialised_. It's good to use the appropriate jargon, like "indeterminant" instead of "random", too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables declared inside of a function that are not explicitly initialized have **indeterminate values**.  Reading a variable with an indeterminate value can lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Such behavior can manifest as reading "garbage" values, though any value including 0 can be considered "garbage", and it's also possible that subsequent reads can result in seeing different values.

However, the Linux kernel code you referenced, unlike your sample code, does *not* declare `averunnable` inside of a function, but instead declares it at file scope.  For variables with *static storage duration*, which include variables declared at file scope, they are initialized to 0 (for numeric types) or NULL (for pointer types) if not explicitly initialized.

Comment: awesome!
I declares it in a file and out of the function, then the initial value is 0!
Thank u so much!

Comment: @benwang It may not always be awesome. Declaring and initializing an automatic variable means that the variable will always be initialized to a known value when the function is called. Static and extern variables are persistent, so a function that uses them will always see the last known value (which you may or may not want). Also, the function would likely be non-reentrant. It’s better practice to keep variable scope as narrow as possible.

Comment: Yes, that is why I like initializing it whenever I am delcaring a variable.